# How to go back to Nouveau driver?

Tags: drivers, .desktop

After I installed Ubuntu on my PC I installed a nvidia driver, and was curious if it's possible to go back to the default nouveau driver. Do I just simply go to Additional Drivers and select the driver or do I have to go through a setup process?

[image]

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: You could try it and then post an answer if it works, or update your question with what doesn't work. I know when Nvidia gets installed Noveau gets blacklisted but I'm sure Ubuntu is smart enough to reverse this setting when you pick Noveau. I up-voted your question so you'll get points and comment back after you post an answer and I'll up-vote that too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just selecting the `nouveau` option and rebooting should reset it. Of course, there's always the chance that might not work, but this should.

Switch to the `nouveau` driver and reboot (which you've probably already done if you tried the first solution). Now, run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-367` to purge the NVIDIA driver and reboot again.

If you don't have the NVIDIA driver, there's no way it can be in use, so purging should work.

Comment: It worked! Just select the drive in Additional drivers! Thanks for the support guys! :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you Thomas. +1 @Zacharee1 on path to 10k :)